# Python gravity simulator behaving strangely

Tags: python, physics, gravity

I'm making a gravity simulation in Python (in 3D with VPython, to be exact) and I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the code, but it behaves strangely when two objects get close to each other.

My inspiration is http://testtubegames.com/gravity.html. Note how you can place two planets with no velocity, they move towards each other, overtake, decelerate and turn back. In my program, they overtake, and decelerate, but only proportionately to the distance, so technically it should never turn back anyway.

I realize that the law f=G*(m1*m2)/r**2 wouldn't work if r (the distance) is or gets too close to 0, so I have included a max-out, so if it is less than 1 it is set to 1 (units not in pixels, by the way), but it still does not work.

Simple logic also suggests that the objects should not react in this way, so the next thing that follows is that I must be missing something.

Here is an extract of the code:

```
from visual import *
a = sphere(x=-10,mass=10, vel=vector())
b = sphere(x=10, mass=10, vel=vector())

while 1:
    rate(20)

    #distance between the two objects, a and b, where a.r.mag would be the magnitude of the vector
    a.r = b.pos - a.pos
    b.r = a.pos - b.pos

    a.force = a.r
    if a.r.mag > 1:
        a.force.mag = (a.mass * b.mass) / a.r.mag**2
    else:
        a.force.mag = (a.mass * b.mass) / 1
    a.vel = a.vel + a.force / a.mass


    b.force = b.r
    if b.r.mag > 1:
        b.force.mag = (a.mass * b.mass) / b.r.mag**2
    else:
        b.force.mag = (a.mass * b.mass) / 1
    b.vel = b.vel + b.force / b.mass

    a.pos = a.pos + a.vel
    b.pos = b.pos + b.vel
```

EDIT: Code re-written in response to shockburner:

```
from visual import *
import sys

limit2 = sys.float_info.min
limit = limit2**0.5
timestep = 0.0005

a = sphere(x=-5,mass=10, vel=vector())
b = sphere(x=5, mass=10, vel=vector())

def force(ob1, ob2):
    ob1.r = ob2.pos - ob1.pos
    ob1.force = ob1.r + vector()
    if ob1.r.mag > limit:
        ob1.force.mag = (ob1.mass * ob2.mass) / ob1.r.mag2
    else:
        ob1.force.mag = (ob1.mass * ob2.mass) / limit2
    return ob1.force

while 1:
    rt = int(1/timestep)
    rate(rt)

    a.acc = force(a, b) / a.mass
    b.acc = force(b, a) / b.mass

    a.pos = a.pos + timestep * (a.vel + timestep * a.acc / 2)
    b.pos = b.pos + timestep * (b.vel + timestep * b.acc / 2)

    a.acc1 = force(a,b) / a.mass
    b.acc1 = force(b,a) / b.mass

    a.vel = a.vel + timestep * (a.acc + a.acc1) / 2
    b.vel = b.vel + timestep * (b.acc + b.acc1) / 2
```

Any help or pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, and if the answer turns out to be idiotically simple (which with me is usually the case) remember I am quite an idiot anyway.

Comment: ... I can't see any *code* in your question. If your problem is a bug of VPython/some library then you should open a ticket in their issue trackers, otherwise you *should* provide a minimal working example that demonstrates your problem in order to enable us to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before too. If you just go directly to Runge-Kutta, everything will sort itself out. This pdf will explain how to incorporate the method: http://spiff.rit.edu/richmond/nbody/OrbitRungeKutta4.pdf. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your problem stems from numerical errors in your integration method. It seems you are using the Euler method which is prone to large numerical errors as it is a first-order integration method. I would recommend [velocity verlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet) for numerically integrating orbits as it is a second-order method that also preserves total energy (kinetic + gravitational potential) to machine precision. This energy conservation generally makes velocity verlet more stable than 4th-order [Runge–Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), because bound orbits stay bound.

Also you might want to consider having a dynamic time step as opposes to a static one. When your particles are closed together velocities and positions change faster. Thus in order to reduce your numerical errors you need to take a smaller time step.

Finally, I would make your limiter (`if a.r.mag > 1:`) as small as possible/practical. I'd try the following:

```
import sys
limit2 = sys.float_info.min
limit = limit2**.5
...
if a.r.mag > limit:
    a.force.mag = (a.mass * b.mass) / a.r.mag**2
else:
    a.force.mag = (a.mass * b.mass) / limit2
...
```

Comment: Ok, so that definitely wasn't idiotically simple. I tried what you suggested, and although cannot be sure that what I've done is right, it's made no difference in what is already happening. I have included my current code in an edit.